# at-rule or selector expected in django html

Tags: html, css, django-models, django-templates, django-context

I have a model in django and I want to call the model's value fields in my style tag for a CSS property
but I face this error
Actually I want to set `background-color` from backend
how can I fix it?
[image]

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: see [*Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). [edit] the question and include code fragments with the *code sample* button (`{}`).

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error, this is just Visual Studio that does not understand that the template is being rendered.

Indeed, the template inspector expects something like:

```
body {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

now given that the `settings.website_background_color` exists, and is valid, it will render that, but the Visual Studio inspector does not know you will *render* the template.

There might however be a problem that Django will ampersand-escape content. You can avoid that with the [**`|safe`** template filter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#safe), but this will *not* remove the warning:

```
body {
  background-color: {{ settings.website_background_color|safe }};
}
```